# Rewrite Url in localhost is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I searched for many documentation, question and answers for rewrite url as given below

**FROM**

```
http://localhost/rewrite/product.php?id=1
```

**To**

```
http://localhost/rewrite/product.php/1
```

Than i use [this online tool](http://www.webtoolhub.com/tn561403-htaccess-url-rewrite.aspx) to generate url rules.
My Rule Is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /id/(.*) product.php?id=$1
```

And i also checked `httpd.conf`. Allooverride is on.

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

But Still This Url Is not changing to desire url. where i am going wrong. i dont have much knowledge in Rewrite and mod_rewrite. so please be patient to me.

Comment: is your loadrewritemodule uncommented in httpd.conf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will redirect http://localhost/product/1 to http://localhost/product.php?id=1

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product/([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)?$ product.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So to setup, create a product.php file in the base of the localhost directory with the following code:

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
```

And then open http://localhost/product/1 and it should display:

```
array(1) {
["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What that rule does is that if you now access for example the URL http://localhost/rewrite/product.php/1, it will map it to the URL http://localhost/rewrite/product.php?id=1, and you will have access to the id GET parameter in code.

It will not convert an url from http://localhost/rewrite/product.php?id=1 to http://localhost/rewrite/product.php/1, you will have to do that yourself in code or with a redirect.